# Call of dba table on stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm new on Oracle database 11g R2,this is for get the information of the tablespace of the database. I run the next code like a `.sql` :

```
select  TABLESPACE_NAME,
INITIAL_EXTENT,
NEXT_EXTENT,
MIN_EXTENTS,
MAX_EXTENTS,
PCT_INCREASE,
STATUS,
CONTENTS
    from    dba_tablespaces
    order   by TABLESPACE_NAME ;
```

and works fine, but when i try it to run in a Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLE_SPACE_INFO AS 
BEGIN
select  TABLESPACE_NAME,
INITIAL_EXTENT,
NEXT_EXTENT,
MIN_EXTENTS,
MAX_EXTENTS,
PCT_INCREASE,
STATUS,
CONTENTS
from    dba_tablespaces
order   by TABLESPACE_NAME ;
END TABLE_SPACE_INFO;
```

I got a compile error:

```
Error(3,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(11,7): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

What is the solution and why its wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle 9i: Synonymed Table Does Not Exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379672/oracle-9i-synonymed-table-does-not-exist)

Comment: it's not the same thing. Here it is about grant by role which works  when run SQL directly but complains when used inside stored PL/SQL code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont have enough privileges to access `dba_tablespaces`. You should grant privileges to the user or grant DBA role before executing a query.

Answer (score 0):

you can use packages for that:

```
  create or replace PACKAGE YourPackge    AS   TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
  PROCEDURE TABLE_SPACE_INFO(T_List OUT T_CURSOR);
  END;

  \

  create or replace   PACKAGE BODY  YourPackge as
  PROCEDURE TABLE_SPACE_INFO(T_List OUT T_CURSOR)
  IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN T_List FOR
  select  TABLESPACE_NAME,
  INITIAL_EXTENT,
  NEXT_EXTENT,
  MIN_EXTENTS,
  MAX_EXTENTS,
  PCT_INCREASE,
  STATUS,
  CONTENTS
  from    dba_tablespaces
  order   by TABLESPACE_NAME ;
  END TABLE_SPACE_INFO;
  END;
```

Comment: Error(7,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Error(15,11): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

i got the same issue and im using system user

Comment: Never use the SYSTEM user @Arquitecto... create your own and grant appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly grant a select on dba_tablespaces to yourself in order to see that table in a package.  Stored procedures or packages don't inherit the role's object-specific privileges of the user.  Such as:

test.sql:

```
create or replace procedure test as
  ret number;
BEGIN
  select count(*) into ret
    from dba_tablespaces;
end;
/

show errors
```

Running it:

```
SQL> @c:\bob\test

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

Errors for PROCEDURE TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored    
5/10     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

SQL> connect sys/syspwd@mydb as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> grant select on dba_tablespaces to myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect myuser/mypwd@mydb
Connected.
SQL> @c:\bob\test

Procedure created.

No errors.
SQL>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. That is a good answer with show-as-you-explain approach. To complete it, just add note about AUTHID CURRENT_USER.